# How to size subviews in HStack by percentage without GeometryReader (SwiftUI)?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, geometryreader, hstack

I've got a simple `HStack` with subviews inside. How can I tell the first subview to be 60% the size of the `HStack` **without using a `GeometryReader`?**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Color.red.opacity(0.3)
            Color.brown.opacity(0.4)
            Color.yellow.opacity(0.6)
        }
    }
}
```

The code above makes each subview the same size. But I want the first one to be 60% regardless of it's content. In this example, it is a color, but it could be anything.
The `HStack` is dynamic in size.

[image]

### Edit: Why no `GeometryReader`?

When I want to place multiple of those HStacks inside a `ScrollView`, they overlap, because the GeometryReader's height is only 10 Point. As mentioned above, the `Color` views could be anything, so I used `VStacks` with cells in it that have dynamic heights.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            ProblematicView()
            ProblematicView()
        }
    }
}

struct ProblematicView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                VStack {
                    Rectangle().frame(height: 20)
                    Rectangle().frame(height: 30)
                    Rectangle().frame(height: 20)
                    Rectangle().frame(height: 40)
                    Rectangle().frame(height: 20)
                }
                .foregroundColor(.red.opacity(0.3))
                .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.6)
                .overlay(Text("60%").font(.largeTitle))
                
                VStack {
                    Rectangle().frame(height: 10)
                    Rectangle().frame(height: 30)
                    Rectangle().frame(height: 20)
                }
                .foregroundColor(.brown.opacity(0.4))
                .overlay(Text("20%").font(.largeTitle))
                
                VStack {
                    Rectangle().frame(height: 5)
                    Rectangle().frame(height: 10)
                    Rectangle().frame(height: 24)
                    Rectangle().frame(height: 10)
                    Rectangle().frame(height: 17)
                    Rectangle().frame(height: 13)
                    Rectangle().frame(height: 10)
                }
                .foregroundColor(.yellow.opacity(0.6))
                .overlay(Text("20%").font(.largeTitle))
            }
        }
        .border(.blue, width: 3.0)
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `GeometryReader`'s frame is too small in height. It should be as high as the `HStack`. That causes the views to overlap.

[image]

Comment: You can set by `.frame` & `UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * (your width ratio)` calculation.

Comment: Why no geometry reader ?

Comment: I am using the `HStack` in a `LazyVStack` inside a `ScrollView` and the `GeometryReader` there defaults to 10 points in height (for reasons I don't know). The "cell" in that Stack is therefore not as high as the content of the `HStack`.

Comment: Show you full code

Comment: Update question like GeometryReader there defaults to 10 points in height (for reasons I don't know). The "cell" in that Stack is therefore not as high as the content of the HStack

Comment: @Cristik I updated the question for clarification on why the height matters.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact reason (might be a bug in `GeometryReader`), but placing the `GeometryReader` outside the `ScrollView`, and passing down its width makes your code behave as you expect.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ScrollView {
                ProblematicView(geoWidth: geo.size.width)
                ProblematicView(geoWidth: geo.size.width)
            }
        }
        .border(.blue, width: 3.0)
    }
}

struct ProblematicView: View {
    let geoWidth: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        // same code, but using geoWidth to compute the relative width
```

Result:
[image]